# linux mint 19, можно сделать чтоб в определенных папках был свой тип сортировки?

Tags: linux-mint

В контекстном меню файлового менеджера Thunar можно выбрать глобальную сортировку ("Упорядочить") - "по имени", "по размеру" и т.д. Можно ли для определенной папки установить локальную сортировку, независимую от глобальной?
Например глобальная - "по дате", а локальная сортировка - "по имени"

Comment: У меня в настройках thunar есть пункт "Remember view settings for each folder". Не пробовали ставить?

Comment: у вас какой линукс? и где в настройках находится этот пункт? Глянул на своем (версия 1.8.9) - не нашел

Comment: Xubuntu 22.04, thunar версии 4.16.10. Судя по тому, что пункт не переведен, его добавили недавно.